# How would continue to assign variables due to user input in a while loop?

Tags: while-loop

I am trying to use a while loop to ask the user for "multiple classes that they have taken and the hours that the class holds" and I need to assign each input as a different variable
i.e. Cal 2, 4 hours     ENGL 101, 3 hours
class1 = cal2, 4 hours    class2 = ENGL101, 3 hours

Thanks!

Comment: What language and where is your code?

Comment: Presumably whatever language you have will support arrays...  Rather than assign each one to a variable name, just add each one to an array.